# Creating Design View alike application in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I want to create a design view alike application in .net. The application will use some industrial components as tool box view and and I want to render those into my design view. There are few properties that I will be setting on this component.

Is there any guess, How should I start on this? Any example application will be helpful.

Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using MVC design 
Pattern .  In this pattern you have 3 components
and main goal of the pattern is to 
separate data from view. So you 
should have module that deals with
all control rendering and you will
have a module that will contains 
all the control and control settings.
Controller module will manage two
modules .

See [example](http://www.cs.wcupa.edu/~rkline/java/mvc-example.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Any small application code example would you like to suggest?

Comment: The task to implement in MVC in your task is not simple, but possible.I updated the answer. It's in java but it does not matter.